# What is the git equivalent of hg summary?

Tags: git, mercurial

What is the git equivalent of 'hg summary'? Especially 'hg summary --remote' ??

I've seen translations for 'hg in', 'hg out', and a bunch of other translated commands, but I never see 'summary'. I'm lazy and want to know everything 'hg summary --remote' would tell me in one simple command. Will I have to write a custom script, or will git tell me that?

For reference, here is what the 'hg summary' command does:
From [https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/summary](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/summary)

> hg summary [--remote]
>
> aliases: sum
>
> summarize working directory state
>
> This generates a brief summary of the working directory state,
>   including parents, branch, commit status, and available updates.
>
> With the --remote option, this will check the default paths for
>   incoming and outgoing changes. This can be time-consuming.
>
> Returns 0 on success.
>
> options:
>
> --remote check for push and pull

also [from the quickstart guide](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/QuickStart)

> The 'summary' command will summarize the state of the working
>   directory. Command names may be abbreviated, so entering just 'hg sum'
>   is enough:
>
> ```
> $ hg sum
> parent: 9632:16698d87ad20 tip
>  util: use sys.argv[0] if $HG is unset and 'hg' is not in PATH
> branch: default
> commit: (clean)
> update: (current)
> ```
>
> Here commit: (clean) means that there no local changes, update:
>   (current) means that the checked out files (in the working directory)
>   are updated to the newest revision in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git status`. This will display the information I believe you are looking for.

Comment: OK. I've been running that command, but I guess I was not looking closely enough at the output. It does not list the changeset I am at unless it is a detached head, though. So I guess you are right; all the information I want is there. I am just being picky about the format. Thanks. (I had a script that used the hg summary output. I guess the port will be less trivial than I hoped.)

Comment: "git status (-s)" is the equivalent of "hg status", that is different from "hg summary".
**Maybe** "git show -s --format=short" is the most similar command.

Answer (score 4):

Moving back to git from hg myself, this is what I do.

```
git show -s
```

`-s` hides diff

Comment: This is definitely a better answer in my opinion. Much closer to hg summary, Thanks!